# How to compute de Bruijn sequences for non-power-of-two-sized alphabets?

Tags: algorithm, string, math

I'm trying to compute [de Bruijn sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_bruijn_sequence) for alphabets which have a number of characters which is *not* a power of two.

For alphabets with a 2^k characters, calculating de Bruijn sequences is easy: There are several simple rules, such as ["Prefer Ones" and "Prefer Opposites"](http://people.clarkson.edu/~aalhakim/Mypapers/PreferOpposite.pdf) which work for generating B(2,n). B(2^k,n) is exactly the same as B(2,kn), if you read the 1s and 0s as binary codes for the actual characters in your alphabet. E.g., you can interpret B(2,8n) as being over n-length sequences of bytes.

Prefer Ones is quite simple: Write n zeros. Then, always write a one unless it would cause the repetition of an n-length string; otherwise, write a zero.

Presently, I don't see how to generalize such rules to non-power-of-two-sized alphabets.

There's a general method for calculating de Bruijn sequences via graphs: Let each n-length sequence generated by your alphabet be a node; put an edge from A to B iff the rightmost n-1 characters of A are the same as the leftmost n-1 characters of B. Label each edge with the last character of the string in the head vertex. Any [Eulerian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) through this graph will generate a de Bruijn sequence, and the peculiar construction we used guarantees that there will be at least one such path. We can use [Fleury's Algorithm](http://www.austincc.edu/powens/+Topics/HTML/05-6/05-6.html) to (nondeterministically) construct an Eulerian path:

1. Choose a vertex.
2. Leave that vertex via some edge and delete that edge, only choosing edges whose deletion would disconnect the vertex from the graph if there is no alternative.
3. Append to your string the label of the edge you just deleted.
4. Goto 2 until all edges are gone.

The resulting string will be a de Bruijn sequence.

This algorithm is somewhat more complex to implement than Prefer Ones. The simplicity of Prefer Ones is that one needs only to consult the output already generated to determine what to do. Is there a straightforward way to generalize Prefer Ones (or, possibly Prefer Opposites) to alphabets of non-power-of-two sizes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is my C++ implementation of the algorithm in Figure 1 from [a paper by Sawada and Ruskey](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.13.2152):

```cpp
void debruijn(unsigned int t,
              unsigned int p,
              const unsigned int k,
              const unsigned int n,
              unsigned int* a,
              boost::function<void (unsigned int*,unsigned int*)> callback)
{
  if (t > n) {
    // we want only necklaces, not pre-necklaces or Lyndon words
    if (n % p == 0) {
      callback(a+1, a+p+1);
    }
  }
  else {
    a[t] = a[t-p];

    debruijn(t+1, p, k, n, a, callback);

    for (unsigned int j = a[t-p]+1; j < k; ++j) {
      a[t] = j;
      debruijn(t+1, t, k, n, a, callback);
    }
  }
}

struct seq_printer {
  const std::vector<char>& _alpha;

  seq_printer(const std::vector<char>& alpha) : _alpha(alpha) {}

  void operator() (unsigned int* a, unsigned int* a_end) const {
    for (unsigned int* i = a; i < a_end; ++i) {
      std::cout << _alpha[*i];
    }
  }
};

...

std::vector<char> alpha;
alpha.push_back('a');
alpha.push_back('b');
alpha.push_back('c');

unsigned int* a = new unsigned int[N+1];
a[0] = 0;

debruijn(1, 1, alpha.size(), N, a, seq_printer(alpha));
if (N > 1) std::cout << alpha[0];
std::cout << std::endl;

delete[] a;
```

The full reference for the paper is: Joe Sawada and Frank Ruskey, "An Efficient Algorithm for Generating Necklaces with Fixed Density", SIAM Journal of Computing *29*:671-684, 1999.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this web page](http://www.theory.csc.uvic.ca/~cos/inf/neck/NecklaceInfo.html) at the combinatorial group of the CS department at UVic, there's a result due to Fredericksen that you can generate a de Bruijn sequence (in fact, the lexicographically smallest one) by concatenating "the lexicographic sequence of [Lyndon words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) of lengths divisible by n".   There's even source code to build the sequence that you can request.

Comment: +1; another place to look for code and a detailed description is the [FXT library and "fxtbook"](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/) (see sections 18.1 and 18.2).

Answer (score 3):

Are you only interested in a generalization of Prefer Ones or do you just want a not so complex algorithm? If the latter is true then maybe Frank Ruskey's recursive implementation could be of help.

A year ago [I translated that one](http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2009/09/27/a-case-for-using-only-three-different-digits-in-keypad-codes) to Ruby.

```ruby
# De Bruijn sequence
# Original implementation by Frank Ruskey (1994)
# translated to C by Joe Sawada
# and further translated to Ruby by Jonas Elfström (2009)

@n=4
@k=10
@a=[0]
@sequence=[]

def debruijn(t, p, alike)
  if t>@n
    if @n%p==0
      1.upto(p) {|j| @sequence<<@a[j]}
    end
  else
    @a[t]=@a[t-p]
    if @a[t]>0
      debruijn(t+1,p,alike+1)
    else
      debruijn(t+1,p,alike)
    end
    (@a[t-p]+1).upto(@k-1) {|j|
      @a[t]=j
      debruijn(t+1,t,alike+1)
    }
  end
end

debruijn(1,1,0)
print @sequence.join
```

Uckelman noticed that the `alike` variable does nothing. The following produces the same sequence.

```ruby
@n=4
@k=10
@a=[0]
@sequence=[]

def debruijn(t, p)
  if t>@n
    if @n%p==0
      1.upto(p) {|j| @sequence<<@a[j]}
    end
  else
    @a[t]=@a[t-p]
    debruijn(t+1,p)
    (@a[t-p]+1).upto(@k-1) {|j|
      @a[t]=j
      debruijn(t+1,t)
    }
  end
end

debruijn(1,1)
print @sequence.join
```

Comment: I'm interested in whether Prefer Ones is extensible somehow, but also other simple algorithms. Thanks. I now have a reason to learn the syntax for Ruby. Heh.

Comment: Is the paper from which you got the algorithm [this one](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=314910)?

Comment: Also, what's the reason for the `alike` parameter? It appears to do nothing.

Comment: I remember finding the C source code on a page somewhere and not in a PDF document. Unfortunately I don't remember where and I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely right that the `alike` does nothing. It was there in the C code and apparently I didn't analyze the code enough.

Comment: Further note: This doesn't quite generate de Bruijn sequences. Rather, for n > 1, it generates everything except the last character. (I know that you can define them as circular strings, so leaving off the last letter is ok in that setting. It's just surprising here, if you were expecting to have the join point represented at both ends.)

Comment: Not a big problem, I suppose?

Comment: I think your original algorithm was a modification of the algorithm given in Figure 2 of Weston and Vajnovszki, "Gray codes for necklaces and Lyndon words of arbitrary base", Pure Mathematics and Applications 17(1-2):175-182, 2006.

Comment: None of the algorithms in the Sawada-Ruskey paper have a third parameter, but the Vajnovszki algorithm does. If you simplify it to the point where the third parameter does nothing, I think you can get what you had. Sawada and Ruskey might have been working from the other direction, though, too. :)

Comment: I'm confused. The source code I converted had comments saying it was written by Ruskey & Sawada but you are clearly the expert among us two so I guess I got something wrong.

Comment: @uckelman, more precisely, for n > 1, the program generates everything except the last _n-1_ characters. For example, B(3,2) returns 001021122, but to have all 3-character sequences you have to add _2_ characters: 001021122*00*.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use:

```py
def de_bruijn(k, n):
    a = [0] * k * n
    sequence = []
    def db(t, p):
        if t > n:
            if n % p == 0:
                for j in range(1, p + 1):
                    sequence.append(a[j])
        else:
            a[t] = a[t - p]
            db(t + 1, p)
            for j in range(a[t - p] + 1, k):
                a[t] = j
                db(t + 1, t)
    db(1, 1)
    return sequence

print de_bruijn(2,9)
```

Comment: Your program's missing some words. Every word's missing for the tuple (k, n) = (0, n); every word 'kk…00' (with `k` = "your input variable k for `de_bruijn`; consisting only of a block of the last letter of the alphabet followed by a block of the first letter) I'm writing something in order to improve this… but I don't know how to fix your code without workaround (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Duval's algorithm does the same thing iteratively (In Python this time):

```py
def debruijn(k, n):
    v = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    l = 1
    r = []
    while True:
        if n % l == 0:
            r.extend(v[0:l])
        for i in range(l, n):
            v[i] = v[i-l]
        l = n
        while l > 0 and v[l-1] >= k-1:
            l-=1
        if l == 0:
            break
        v[l-1] += 1
    return r

print(debruijn(3,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @stefan-gruenwald's code, which lacks [a simply categorizable set of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008603/how-to-compute-de-bruijn-sequences-for-non-power-of-two-sized-alphabets#comment106526172_22873855). Although I'm not capable (yet) to emend it, I wrote some lines for finding the error, which seems to be

```py
import itertools

def debruijn (k, n) :
    v =  [ 0 for _ in range (n) ]
    l = 1
    r =  []
    while True :
        if n % l == 0 :
            r.extend (v [0:l])
        for i in range (l, n) :
            v [i] = v [i-l]
        l = n
        while l > 0 and v [l-1] >= k-1 :
            l -= 1
        if l == 0 :
            break
        v [l-1] += 1
    return r

K = int (input ( 'k ' ) )
N = int (input ( 'n ' ) )

for k in range (K) :                                # length of alphabet
    for n in range (N) :                            # length of word(s)
        List = debruijn (k, n)
        l = ''
        for L in List :
            l += str (L)
        L = itertools.product (range (k), repeat = n)
        print ( 'alphabet k', k, '\tword n', n, str ('|' + l + '|') )
        for a in L :
            searchstr = ''
            for A in a :
                searchstr += str (A)
            if not searchstr in l :
                print ( searchstr, end = ' ' )
        print ()
```

Also saveable in a file:

```py
import itertools

def debruijn (k, n) :
    v =  [ 0 for _ in range (n) ]
    l = 1
    r =  []
    while True :
        if n % l == 0 :
            r.extend (v [0:l])
        for i in range (l, n) :
            v [i] = v [i-l]
        l = n
        while l > 0 and v [l-1] >= k-1 :
            l -= 1
        if l == 0 :
            break
        v [l-1] += 1
    return r

K = int (input ( 'k ' ) )
N = int (input ( 'n ' ) )

for k in range (K) :                                # length of alphabet
    for n in range (N) :                            # length of word(s)
        List = debruijn (k, n)
        l = ''
        for L in List :
            l += str (L)
        L = itertools.product (range (k), repeat = n)
        with open (str (k) + '-' + str (n), 'w') as f :
            f.write ( 'alphabet length ' + str (k) + '\tword length ' + str (n) + '\n' + l + '\nnot in:\n' )
            for a in L :
                searchstr = ''
                for A in a :
                    searchstr += str (A)
                if not searchstr in l :
                    f.write ( searchstr + ' ' )
```