# What is the shortest string of numbers, which contains all the numbers between 0 and 1000

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm sat at my desk and I just thought up a problem and I was wondering if anyone could think up a solution or a way to prove this mathematically.

Say I wanted to find the shortest string of numbers, which contained every number between 0 and 1000. For example, the string "1433" contains the numbers, 1, 4, 3, 14, 43, 33, 143, and 433.

What algorithm could I use to construct the shortest string which contained all numbers 0-1000.

I don't have any practical reason why I want to know, but I'd be interested to hear if there is one.

Comment: At a glance, it looks NP-complete. But that's just a guess.

Comment: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/21050.html might help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008603/how-to-compute-de-bruijn-sequences-for-non-power-of-two-sized-alphabets

Comment: I came to ask the same question only for all sequences of 00000 to 55555 using base 5 -- I want to test the security of the keyless entry keypad on my car. For this I've found a sample superstring online but I want to find the shortest possible. It looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008603/ has the closest solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking for a modified [de Bruijn sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).  Specifically, a de Bruijn sequence with the first n-1 characters appended to the end of the string.

For the particular case you ask about, it will be 10^3 + 2 = 1002 digits long (assuming that 1000 is not included -- you can arrange for 1000 to be in the string as well, if you set things up right, but there is no guarantee that an arbitrarily chosen (10,3) de Bruijn sequence will contain "1000").

Comment: There is no reason to include 000 or 001 etc in the string. Thus the solution can be shortened to 999 digits.